# Is there a way to re-generate a serialVersionUID in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

I know that Eclipse can create a new `serialVersionUID` when you don't yet have one, but I'm looking for a way to generate a new one after you made some changes.

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464529/eclipse-auto-generation-of-serialversionuid-with-each-change), I'm not looking for a tool to have it changed by itself, but rather a menu item / hotkey that does the trick. Anything faster than removing it and let Eclipse generate a new one would do.

I'm aware of this [Ant tool](http://serialver.sourceforge.net/), but I prefer something in Eclipse.

Comment: If you want it to change whenever you make some changes to the class then just remove it. serialVersionUID is intended for when you do not want it to change when you change the definition of the class.

Comment: I want it to change only when I make changes that affect the serializability.

Comment: ... and if you want to change it only sometimes, you can just make a random modification to this number -- assuming you do not release more often than once a day, this should be safe enough.

Comment: Good point, that would be an acceptable answer in fact, didn't think of that.

Comment: @BevynQ `serialVersionUID` is intended as a way to version your class definitions, reliably, across compilers/environments/etc. Whether or not that matters depends on how serialization is being used, and whether or not the changes affect ser/deser.

Comment: The answer is given so I can only give you a recommendation. Assuming you don't have releases every hour why do you even care if you break serializability _in between_ releases? You'll want to make sure the serialVersionUID changes when you release, though. Spring for example references a constant from all their serialVersionUIDs and the constant value is...the release version. I'm sure it gets updated automatically before the code is compiled during a release build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I do not know of any such plug-in available.

However, the Ant tool you could create a single Ant script to modify your projects, and you can add that script either as an External tool (runnable from the menu of a project) or even as an incremental builder (that needs more time to set up correctly).

I wrote a blog post some time ago, when I used an Ant script to [generate code from EMF models](http://cubussapiens.hu/2010/12/generating-java-code-from-emf-models-automatically/) automatically when the source models change. That script works fine in our codebase with a single known issue: the build is sometimes triggered unexpectedly...

Comment: Is it possible to use the Ant script for a single class?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can set properties using workspace variables - those variables can e.g. define the selected file for the Ant script.